# ¿Cuándo debo usar Herencia, Interface o una Clase Abstracta?

Tags: poo, herencia, interface, clase-abstracta

Mi cuestionamiento es una duda que tengo hace unos días y es ¿Cuándo debo utilizar una Herencia, Interface y una Clase Abstracta?
Según lo que sé, estas son las características de las tres:

Clase Abstracta (¿se pueden declarar variables dentro de una clase abstracta?)

- Declaran métodos pero no los implementan (¿Qué significa que no los implementa?)
- Al menos un método es abstracto
- No se pueden instanciar

Interface

- Implementan métodos pero no los utiliza
- Todos los métodos son abstractos
- No se pueden instanciar
- Las variables se declaran con "modificador acceso + *static* + *final* + nombre"

Herencia

- Reutilización de variables y métodos

Comment: Esta es una pregunta teorica y no tiene ningun sentido cerrarla, no todas las preguntas tienen q llevar codigo

Comment: ¿Por qué cerraron la pregunta? Las preguntas teóricas no son basadas en opiniones, **LA TEORÍA NO ES UNA OPINIÓN**

Comment: Claro que es basada es opiniones, este es un tema muy debatido. La única interpretación no basada en opiniones sería tomarla como que pregunta por las diferencias. Pero el OP no especifica un lenguaje y las limitaciones de las interfaces y clases abstractas varían ligeramente entre lenguajes. Si te interesa mi opinión, deberías preferir siempre interfaces sobre clases abstractas y composición sobre herencia. Si quieres argumentos googlea "inheritance is evil"

Comment: No está preguntando si la herencia es buena o mala o si prefieres usar interfaces o clases abstractas. La teoría especifica bien qué casos debes considerar para elegir una interfaz o una clase abstracta. Y claro que la implementación varia de lenguaje a lenguaje, pero los conceptos se mantienen igual.

Comment: Cuando la pregunta no es lo suficientemente clara puede tener distintas interpretaciones. Aunque tu respuesta no sea una opinión, la pregunta si se presta a opiniones. Puedes ver que almenos cuatro personas la consideraron basada en opiniones. Si estás seguro de lo que pregunta puedes proponer una edición para hacerla más específica.

Comment: Tratando de ser lo más objetivo he analizado esta pregunta, desde el inicio encontré que está bien escrita: Es directa, tiene buena ortografía, tiene investigación previa y desde mi parecer pregunta por teoría, no por opiniones. "¿Cuándo debo utilizar una Herencia, Interface y una Clase Abstracta?", si alguien responde con opiniones, entonces es culpa de quien respondió, no del autor de la pregunta. Hice la respuesta tratando de ser objetivo. Pero a lo largo de mi estancia en SOes, he visto que las preguntas teóricas no son bien recibidas, por eso me esforcé bastante en la respuesta.

Comment: "desde mi parecer pregunta por teoría" esto es sólo tu interpretación, la pregunta no dice buscar una respuesta puramente teórica. En la práctica las relaciones entre clases se pueden modelar de distintas maneras que en gran medida dependen del lenguaje que emplees. Si tu respuesta es teórica no deberías dar tantos detalles de la implementación en Java porque no todas esas características se cumplen otros lenguajes. La verdadera respuesta a esta pregunta es "usa lo que tenga más sentido para ti o lo que mejor se ajuste a la arquitectura de tu proyecto"

Comment: Entre una bicicleta, un auto y un avión ¿Cuándo debo utilizar cada uno? Depende... de un contexto, del objetivo, de las prioridades, de las posibilidades, etc. incluso los gustos. La pregunta, si bien es legítima, es tan abierta que puede abarcar un capítulo de un libro. Tan solo POO vs Funcional ya es tema de debate. Podrías encontrar inspiración leyendo sobre [*Patrones de Diseño*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o).

Comment: Que lenguaje usas?, por ejemplo en algún lenguaje puede no existir la herencia múltiple puede ser que en otro lenguaje exista. **Para determinar que usar, puedes iniciar por leer la teoría**:  [Concepto de interface y herencia múltiple en Java. Implements. Ejemplos y diagramas de clases.](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=669:concepto-de-interface-y-herencia-multiple-en-java-implements-ejemplos-y-diagramas-de-clases-cu00696b&catid=68&Itemid=188) , te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 9):

## Teoría

### Herencia, clases abstractas, interfaces y polimorfismo

---

A mí me gusta bastante explicar este tema con la biología y la tecnología.

Para empezar podemos ver 2 tipos de herencia:

1. **Herencia única:** Es como la [taxonomía](https://portalacademico.cch.unam.mx/biologia2/caracteristicas-generales-dominios-y-reinos/categorias-taxonomicas) en biología

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. **Herencia múltiple:** Una subclase hereda de 2 o más super clases, y esta obtiene TODAS las propiedades de TODOS sus padres, aunque ofrece algunos beneficios a la hora de programar, se debe de lidiar con el [problema diamante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_del_diamante).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Nótese la forma de diamante

**Característica importante de la herencia de Clases**

Lo que se hereda mediante clases no se planea para cambiar. Es decir, que las acciones heredadas ya están definidas y aunque se pueden cambiar, la buena práctica sería evitar hacerlo.

**¿Pero qué pasa si yo quiero que hereden acciones pero tengan comportamiento diferente?**

Para ello están las clases abstractas. Las clases abstractas sirven para abstraer información. Se hace una abstracción del mundo real, se definen las propiedades y ojo: se definen los métodos (acciones), pero no se especifica su comportamiento. Esto es muy útil por ejemplo cuando tienes dos figuras geométricas. Podrías definir que tienen propiedades como: color, tamaño de lado, número de lados, nombre, entre otros. Pero sus acciones son diferentes. Por ejemplo, el cálculo de área o de volumen.

**¿Y las interfaces?**

Primero hay que quitarse de la cabeza que una interfaz o *interface* es algo gráfico **¡NO!**. Una interfaz en la POO es más bien un contrato.

Las interfaces son más generales y me gusta relacionarlo con la tecnología, una interfaz es la manera en la que nos comunicamos con algo sin saber cómo funciona internamente. Por ejemplo, un radio tiene una interfaz que nos permite apagarlo, cambiar de estación, subir el volumen y acciones similares, la televisión lo mismo (aunque funcionan internamente muy distinto).

Nosotros podemos usar a través de una interfaz una radio sin conocer nada de circuitos o cómo se hace la transformación de una onda electromagnética a una sonora. Y con la misma interfaz (encender, apagar, cambiar de canal, subir/bajar el volumen), podemos interactuar con la televisión que es totalmente distinta a la radio.

## Explicación a detalle

---

### Herencia

#### **Herencia única, ¿Qué es?**

En pocas palabras es heredar características comunes a diferentes objetos; un objeto de software heredará TODAS las características de su padre. **Solamente pueden tener un padre**

Si lo vemos desde la biología, un organismo no puede pertenecer a dos reinos distintos. Pongamos un ejemplo sencillo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un hombre y una mujer heredan las características de un ser humano

- Ser bípedo
- Consciencia
- Manos con pulgares

A su vez, un humano, una medusa y un gusano tienen las características de un ser vivo

- Irritabilidad
- Nutrición
- Reproducción
- Muerte, entre otros

Cabe resaltar que:

- Un hombre o una mujer tienen por consecuencia, las características de un ser vivo
- Tratar de heredar de dos o más padres distintos sería como decir que un hombre es una medusa y un ser humano a la vez o que una mujer es un pingüino y un ser humano. Obviamente esto no es posible

Algunos lenguajes con herencia única: Java, Nemerle, Delphi, C#, Objective-C

##### Herencia múltiple, ¿Qué es?

> "Herencia múltiple hace referencia a la característica de los lenguajes de programación orientada a objetos en la que una clase puede heredar comportamientos y características de más de una superclase." (colaboradores de Wikipedia, 2021)

Esto introduce algunos problemas de ambigüedad:

Si retomamos la imagen del problema diamante vemos que en memoria pasaría que se tienen 2 veces las propiedades de animal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues vemos que Carnívoro tiene propiedades de animal y Herbívoro tiene igual sus propiedades de animal. La solución a este problema varía de lenguaje a lenguaje pues hay diferentes soluciones pero eso sería ya investigarlo en el lenguaje que se aplique.

**Aún más problemas de ambigüedad**

> La herencia múltiple introduce la posibilidad de que los nombres se hereden a lo largo de más de un camino. Los nombres de los miembros de clase a lo largo de estas rutas no son necesariamente únicos. Estos conflictos de nombres se llaman "ambigüedades". (Microsoft, 2018)

Imaginemos que Herbívoro y Carnívoro tienen la propiedad comida, el ser omnívoro heredaría esa propiedad comida de ambas pero cuando haga referencia a Omnívoro.comida, ¿Será la comida del herbívoro o del carnívoro?

Lo mismo pasa con los métodos.

Algunos lenguajes con herencia múltiple: C++, CLOS, Eiffel, Object REXX, Perl, Python.

### Clases abstractas

Una clase abstracta no puede ser invocada pero sí extendida como objeto

- Una clase no abstracta que extienda de una clase abstracta debe incluir las implementaciones de todos los métodos abstractos heredados
- Sus métodos abstractos sólo son la definición, no realizan ninguna acción
- Puede tener métodos no abstractos
- Puede tener variables no estáticas
- Un método abstracto no puede ser estático, pues los principios se contradicen

### Interfaces

Una interfaz es similar a una clase abstracta, funciona como un "tipo de clase" que oculta su funcionamiento interno, es bastante útil para definir acciones compartidas que esperas de algo.

> Hay una serie de situaciones en la ingeniería de software cuando es importante que grupos dispares de programadores acuerden un "contrato" que explique cómo interactúa su software. Cada grupo debe poder escribir su código sin saber cómo se escribe el código del otro grupo. En términos generales, las interfaces son tales contratos. (Oracle, s.f.)

- Sólo pueden ser implementadas por otras clases
- Pueden ser heredadas en otras interfaces
- Su cuerpo puede contener: métodos abstractos, predeterminados y estáticos
- Sólo puede tener constantes, no puede cambiarse el valor de NADA
- Puedes implementar varias interfaces, normalmente sepáradas por una coma.
- Es muy similar a una clase abstracta. Pero se diferencian en que una interfaz no puede tener métodos no abstractos no estáticos y no puede tener variables sólo constantes.

### ¿Entonces cuándo usar una clase abstracta o una interfaz?

| Clase abstracta | Interfaz |
| --- | --- |
| Cuando quieres compartir código entre clases estrechamente relacionadas | Quieres que clases sin ninguna relación cercana usen tu interfaz |
| Esperas que las clases que extiendan tu clase abstracta tengan variables y métodos en común | Te interesa especificar el comportamiento de cierto dato, pero no te importa en qué se utilice |
| Quieres que las variables y métodos de la clase sean variables y no sean estáticas. | Quieres que una clase implemente muchas interfaces que no tengan nada que ver entre sí. |

### Polimorfismo (Más biología)

> “El polimorfismo implica una de dos o más variantes de una secuencia particular de ADN” (NHGRI, s.f.)

Esto, en pocas palabras dice que un organismo o una especie puede tener diferentes formas, tamaños o etapas.

El principio anterior puede aplicarse a la POO. Las subclases de una clase, pueden definir sus propios comportamientos y aún así, compartir características con su padre y por tanto, de otras clases que hayan heredado de la súper clase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algunas referencias:

- Oracle. (s. f.-a). Abstract Methods and Classes. Recuperado el 31 de mayo de 2020, de https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html
- Oracle. (s. f.-b). Interfaces. Recuperado el  31 de mayo de 2020, de https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html
- Oracle. (s. f.-b). Defining an Interface. Recuperado 31 de mayo de 2020, de https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html
- National Human Genome Research Institute. (s. f.). Polimorfismo | NHGRI. Recuperado 10 de junio de 2020, de https://www.genome.gov/es/genetics-glossary/Polimorfismo
- colaboradores de Wikipedia. (2021, July 4). Herencia múltiple. Wikipedia, la enciclopedia libre. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herencia_m%C3%BAltiple
- Microsoft. (2018, November 19). Multiple Base Classes. Microsoft Docs. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/multiple-base-classes?view=msvc-160

### Sobre los métodos abstractos (usando Java como referencia)

> Declaran métodos pero no los implementan (¿Qué significa que no los implementa?)

Yo lo aprendí como: Se declaran métodos pero no se define su implementación. Es decir, sólo se indica la firma del método.

```java
public abstract class SerVivo {
    // Las clases abtractas pueden tener variables
    private int age;
    private String name;
    public SerVivo(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // Se declara y define su comportamiento
    public void death(){
        System.out.println("R.I.P.");
    }
    // Se declara únicamente
    public abstract void breath();
    public abstract void feed();
    public abstract void reproduce();
}
```

Cuando una clase abstracta hereda de otra una clase abstracta, se pueden o no definir los métodos

```java
public abstract class Worm extends SerVivo {
    
    public Worm(int age, String name) {
        super(int age, String name);
    }
    // Se define el comportamiento del método
    @Override
    public void breath() {
        System.out.println("Respiro por la piel");
    }
    // Se define el comportamiento del método
    @Override
    public void feed(){
        System.out.println("Como bacterias y hongos. ¡Yummi yummi!");
    }
    // Nótese que no se define la manera de reproducción
    // Se sigue manteniendo como un método abstracto
}
```

Cuando se hereda por una clase no abstracta, se debe de definir el comportamiento de todos los métodos abstractos.

```java
public class SexualWorm extends Worm {
    
    public SexualWorm(int age, String name) {
        super(int age, String name);
    }

    @Override
    public void reproduce(){
        System.out.println("Me reproduzco de manera sexual aunque sea hermafrodita, pues no me puedo auto fecundar");
    }
    // Obviamente puede tener sus propios métodos
    public void getFertility(){
        System.out.println("Soy hermafrodita y tengo la capacidad de fecundar y ser fecundado");
    }

}
```

```java
public class AsexualWorm extends Worm {
    
    public AsexualWorm(int age, String name) {
        super(int age, String name);
    }

    @Override
    public void reproduce(){
        System.out.println("Me reproduzco de manera asexual no necesito a nadie más");
    }

}
```

**Importante:**

- Los `AsexualWorm` y `SexualWorm` tienen todas las variables y métodos de `Worm` que a su vez tiene todas las variables y métodos de `SerVivo`

Comment: Con el debido respeto y espero acepte una crítica constructiva, pero está mal, no solo eso cantinfleas "mucho" y al final no dices nada, por ejemplo: **Herencia**: _es heredar_, **Polimorfismo** _imlica una de dos o más variantes de una secuencia particular de ADN_ y mi favorita **Clase Abstracta** _Las clases abstractas sirven para abstraer información. Se hace una abstracción del mundo real_. Entre otros

Comment: No porque Java no tenga herencia múltiple no quiere decir que no exista. **C++** tiene herencia múltiple, "Typescript" podíamos decir que tiene herencia multiple

Comment: @JSDisciple Ya agregué lo de la herencia múltiple, pues ignoraba su existencia y sobre lo de "cantinflear" es porque he enseñado este tema algunas veces y créeme que es difícil comprender este tema a la primera, dar una explicación breve y decir que algo abstracto es una abstracción lo hace más comprensible, esto ya es tema de docencia o pedagogía. Enseña de la manera más clara.

Comment: Tiene varias concepciones erróneas; aunque la intención sea buena, perjudica mas que beneficiar. Cantidad no es calidad.